# Do PNGs compressed multiple times require multiple decompressions?

Tags: png

If my PNGs get compressed multiple times, do they need to be decompressed the same number of times?
I need my PNGs to load darn fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they will only need to be decompressed once, although I understand if you've had confusion with this as there are a number of tools like pngcrush that will try compressing the file many times (in different ways) to determine the most efficient method.

Comment: If you like the answer, mark it, it helps us keep working through the questions. Thanks! :D

Comment: Ah ok! I've only been here a few days. :)